# What could be causing the issues with sharing an Android app?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an option in an app to share a download link with people. Below is what I have. What is the issue?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    boolean start = true;
    String test = "google.com";

    switch (v.getId()) {
    (...)
    case R.id.share:
        start = false;
        Intent send = new Intent();
        send.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, test);
        send.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(send);
        break;
    }

    if (start)
        startActivity(intent);  //line 135
}
```

At the end of the switch, if start is false it will not perform startActivity(), since it is doing so inside the case for share. However, when I clock on this in the app i get the following error...

```
 02-19 11:55:01.630: E/AndroidRuntime(27279): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
```

And this references line 135, which would be the second "startActivity()". anyone have any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Intent isn't set, as you send `Intent send`.

Why do you have line 135 at all since you already send the email in `startActivity(send)`?

Answer (score 0):

Change line 135 from

```
startActivity(intent);  //line 135
```

to

```
startActivity(send);  //line 135
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the if(start) block, the intent was never correctly initialized with the action and other arguments. I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but you need something like this:

```
if (start) {
    // Set appropriate parameters here...
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, test);
    intent.setType("text/plain");

    startActivity(intent);  //line 135
}
```